# How to instal and run dotnet command and .NET Core on Windows Server 2012 RC2?

Tags: .net-framework, windows-server-2012-r2, dll

I installed the [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle) on Windows Server 2012 RC2 x64. When I try to run `dotnet` command, I get this error:

[image]

After some googling, I found out that I should install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 RC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685) as well.

When I try to do this, I get the following error:

[image: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.]

The log:

```
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{95AC377C-821C-438D-8F86-0D598ABA2DE8} {92791C7B-0474-411B-8C29-D9A072A55A97} 4552'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20171006032526.log'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.24123'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:26]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20171006032526_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20171006032526_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20171006032526_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20171006032526_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i300: Apply begin
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i362: System restore disabled, system restore point not created.
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}\.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}, version: 14.0.24123.0
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FDBE9DB4-7A91-3A28-B27E-705EF7CFAE57}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FDBE9DB4-7A91-3A28-B27E-705EF7CFAE57}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{21134089-9B59-34C8-BE11-929D26AD5207}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{21134089-9B59-34C8-BE11-929D26AD5207}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows81_x64.
[11C8:11E8][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows81_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:28]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FDBE9DB4-7A91-3A28-B27E-705EF7CFAE57}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i325: Registering dependency: {2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{21134089-9B59-34C8-BE11-929D26AD5207}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i325: Registering dependency: {2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:29]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:29]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:29]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[11C8:11CC][2017-10-06T03:25:29]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[11D4:11D8][2017-10-06T03:25:30]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Specifically this part might be important: *Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.*

As suggested in comments, I also tried the [KB2999226](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d3edacc7-425a-4cc5-b5f2-512e0682e88e) update. Another error:

[image: This update is not applicable to your computer]

I thought .NET Core was supposed to run correctly in Windows Server 2012 without any problems. What is I do wrong? How to install it properly?

Comment: The api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll that you're missing comes in Windows update [KB2999226](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d3edacc7-425a-4cc5-b5f2-512e0682e88e)

Comment: @n8te Thanks for reply. That update cannot be installed on the machine. Maybe it's already installed or broken.

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bc483ae5-1934-4775-b648-d9144c1ac60f/i-need-help-with-my-c-redistributable-2015-x64-please?forum=vssetup) may be relevant to your problem.

Comment: You are 100% sure you downloaded the correct package? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows because you need that KB installed to solve this problem.  You actually mean Windows Server 2012 R2 correct?

Comment: Tomas, simple solution that worked for me in the past on a server build that I documented in case you find this fixes your issue `1.` install [KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2919355/windows-rt-8-1--windows-8-1--and-windows-server-2012-r2-update-april-2), reboot the machine, install [KB2919442](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42153), reboot and now install the C++ 2015~ package. The files downloaded for me that I installed were named `Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu` and `Windows8.1-KB2919442-x64.msu` by the way; I think I was build a MySQL Server.